# ActionListener just works with one button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a panel with other two panels inside it. The problem is that the `ActionListener` only is working with the first buttons that is in the first panel, but the buttons in the second panel do not work. What have I done wrong?

```
package vista;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import logica.Empresa;

public class PanelPagos extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JPanel panelBusqueda;
private JPanel panelCuotas;

///////////////////////////////////
private JLabel labelId;
private JTextField txtId;
private JButton buttonBuscar;

//////////////////////////////////

private JLabel labelPago1;
private JLabel labelPago2;
private JLabel labelPago3;
private JLabel labelPago4;
private JLabel labelPago5;
private JLabel labelPago6;
private JLabel labelPago7;
private JLabel labelPago8;
private JLabel labelPago9;
private JLabel labelPago10;
private JLabel labelPago11;
private JLabel labelPago12;

private JButton btnPago1;
private JButton btnPago2;
private JButton btnPago3;
private JButton btnPago4;
private JButton btnPago5;
private JButton btnPago6;
private JButton btnPago7;
private JButton btnPago8;   
private JButton btnPago9;
private JButton btnPago10;
private JButton btnPago11;
private JButton btnPago12;

private JLabel labelPagoCompleto;

public PanelPagos() {

    panelBusqueda = new JPanel();
    panelCuotas = new JPanel();

    labelId = new JLabel("ID:");
    txtId = new JTextField(10);
    buttonBuscar = new JButton("Buscar");
    buttonBuscar.addActionListener(this);

    panelBusqueda.add(labelId);
    panelBusqueda.add(txtId);
    panelBusqueda.add(buttonBuscar);

    ///////////////////////////////

    labelPago1 = new JLabel("Pago #1: ");
    labelPago1.setEnabled(false);
    labelPago2 = new JLabel("Pago #2: ");
    labelPago2.setEnabled(false);
    labelPago3 = new JLabel("Pago #3: ");
    labelPago3.setEnabled(false);
    labelPago4 = new JLabel("Pago #4: ");
    labelPago4.setEnabled(false);
    labelPago5 = new JLabel("Pago #5: ");
    labelPago5.setEnabled(false);
    labelPago6 = new JLabel("Pago #6: ");
    labelPago6.setEnabled(false);
    labelPago7 = new JLabel("Pago #7: ");
    labelPago7.setEnabled(false);
    labelPago8 = new JLabel("Pago #8: ");
    labelPago8.setEnabled(false);
    labelPago9 = new JLabel("Pago #9: ");
    labelPago9.setEnabled(false);
    labelPago10 = new JLabel("Pago #10: ");
    labelPago10.setEnabled(false);
    labelPago11 = new JLabel("Pago #11: ");
    labelPago11.setEnabled(false);
    labelPago12 = new JLabel("Pago #12: ");
    labelPago12.setEnabled(false);

    btnPago1 = new JButton("Pagar");
    btnPago1.addActionListener(this);
    btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
    btnPago2 = new JButton("Pagar");
    btnPago2.addActionListener(this);
    btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
    btnPago3 = new JButton("Pagar");
    btnPago3.addActionListener(this);
    btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
    btnPago4 = new JButton("Pagar");
    btnPago4.addActionListener(this);
    btnPago4.setEnabled(false);
    btnPago5 = new JButton("Pagar");
    btnPago5.addActionListener(this);
    btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
    btnPago6 = new JButton("Pagar");
    btnPago6.addActionListener(this);
    btnPago6.setEnabled(false);
    btnPago7 = new JButton("Pagar");
    btnPago7.addActionListener(this);
    btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
    btnPago8 = new JButton("Pagar");
    btnPago8.addActionListener(this);
    btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
    btnPago9 = new JButton("Pagar");
    btnPago9.addActionListener(this);
    btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
    btnPago10 = new JButton("Pagar");
    btnPago10.addActionListener(this);
    btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
    btnPago11 = new JButton("Pagar");
    btnPago11.addActionListener(this);
    btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
    btnPago12 = new JButton("Pagar");
    btnPago12.addActionListener(this);
    btnPago12.setEnabled(false);

    panelCuotas.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    panelCuotas.add(labelPago1, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    panelCuotas.add(btnPago1, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    panelCuotas.add(labelPago2, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    panelCuotas.add(btnPago2, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    panelCuotas.add(labelPago3, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    panelCuotas.add(btnPago3, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    panelCuotas.add(labelPago4, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    panelCuotas.add(btnPago4, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    panelCuotas.add(labelPago5, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    panelCuotas.add(btnPago5, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    panelCuotas.add(labelPago6, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    panelCuotas.add(btnPago6, gbc);

    /////////////////////////////////

    this.add(panelBusqueda);
    this.add(panelCuotas);


}

public String getTxtId() {
    return txtId.getText();
}


public void setTxtId(String txtId) {
    this.txtId.setText(txtId);
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
    Empresa e = Empresa.getInstance();

    if  (evento.getSource() == buttonBuscar){
        System.out.println("Oprimiste Buscar");
        if (e.buscarCliente(getTxtId())==true) {                    

            if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==0) {
                btnPago1.setEnabled(true);
                btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
                btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
                btnPago4.setEnabled(false);
                btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
                btnPago6.setEnabled(false);
                btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
                btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
                btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
                btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
                btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
                btnPago12.setEnabled(false);                    
            }

            if (evento.getSource()==btnPago1) {
                System.out.println("dddddd");
                System.out.println(e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas());
                System.out.println("boton 1");
                System.out.println(e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas());
                e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().setCuotasPagas(1);                      
            }               

        }else if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==1) {
            btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago1.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago2.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago4.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago6.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago12.setEnabled(false);
            if (evento.getSource()==btnPago2) {
                e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().setCuotasPagas(2);                      
            }
        } else if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==2) {
            btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago1.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago2.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago3.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago4.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago6.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago12.setEnabled(false);
            if (evento.getSource()==btnPago3) {
                e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().setCuotasPagas(3);                      
            } 
        }else if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==3) {
            btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago1.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago2.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago3.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago4.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago6.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago12.setEnabled(false);
            if (evento.getSource()==btnPago4) {
                e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().setCuotasPagas(4);
            } 
        }else if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==4) {
            btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago1.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago2.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago3.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago4.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago4.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago5.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago6.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago12.setEnabled(false);
            if (evento.getSource()==btnPago5) {
                e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().setCuotasPagas(5);
            }
        }else if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==5) {
            btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago1.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago2.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago3.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago4.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago3.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago3.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago6.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago12.setEnabled(false);
            if (evento.getSource()==btnPago6) {
                e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().setCuotasPagas(6);
            }
        }else if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==6) {
            btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago1.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago2.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago3.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago4.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago4.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago5.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago6.setEnabled(false); 
            btnPago6.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago7.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago12.setEnabled(false);
            if (evento.getSource()==btnPago7) {
                e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().setCuotasPagas(7);
            }
        }else if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==7) {
            btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago1.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago2.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago3.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago4.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago4.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago5.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago6.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago6.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago7.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago8.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago12.setEnabled(false);
            if (evento.getSource()==btnPago8) {
                e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().setCuotasPagas(8);
            }
        }else if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==8) {
            btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago1.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago2.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago3.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago4.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago4.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago5.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago6.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago6.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago7.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago8.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago9.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago12.setEnabled(false);
            if (evento.getSource()==btnPago9) {
                e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().setCuotasPagas(9);
            }
        }else if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==9) {
            btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago1.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago2.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago3.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago4.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago4.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago5.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago6.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago6.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago7.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago8.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago9.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago10.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago12.setEnabled(false);
            if (evento.getSource()==btnPago10) {
                e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().setCuotasPagas(10);
            }
        }else if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==10) {
            btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago1.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago2.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago3.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago4.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago4.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago5.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago6.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago6.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago7.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago8.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago9.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago10.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago12.setEnabled(false);
            if (evento.getSource()==btnPago11) {
                e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().setCuotasPagas(11);
            }
        }else if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==11) {
            btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago1.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago2.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago3.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago4.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago4.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago5.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago6.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago6.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago7.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago8.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago9.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago10.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago11.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago12.setEnabled(true);
            if (evento.getSource()==btnPago12) {
                e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().setCuotasPagas(12);
            }
        }else if (e.mostrarLista().get(e.calcularPosicion(getTxtId())).getPagos().getCuotasPagas()==12) {
            btnPago1.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago1.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago2.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago2.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago3.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago3.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago4.setEnabled(true);
            btnPago4.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago5.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago5.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago6.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago6.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago7.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago7.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago8.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago8.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago9.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago9.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago10.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago10.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago11.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago11.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            btnPago12.setEnabled(false);
            btnPago12.setToolTipText("Cuota ya paga");
            if (btnPago1.isEnabled()==false && btnPago2.isEnabled()==false && btnPago3.isEnabled()==false && btnPago4.isEnabled()==false && 
                    btnPago5.isEnabled()==false && btnPago6.isEnabled()==false && btnPago7.isEnabled()==false && btnPago8.isEnabled()==false && 
                    btnPago9.isEnabled()==false && btnPago10.isEnabled()==false && btnPago11.isEnabled()==false && btnPago12.isEnabled()==false) {
                labelPagoCompleto = new JLabel("TODAS LAS CUOTAS ESTAN PAGAS. DIRIGETE AL CENTRO PARA MANTENER, MODIFICAR O ELIMINAR TU MEMBRESIA");
                this.add(labelPagoCompleto);
            }               

        }

    }   
}
}
```

Comment: Cannot read 500+ line of code. Couple of things: 1. Don't compare String with == instead you equals or equalsIgnoreCase. 2. Your whole actionPerformed code will be executed only for one button buttonBuscar since you have placed the entire logic inside if (evento.getSource() == buttonBuscar) {

Comment: What are you doing in `actionPerformed` when the event from the other buttons comes in? That is, when `evento.getSource() != buttonBuscar`?

Comment: When posting questions, your example should be a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). Take note particularly to the minimal part.

Comment: @fishinear Ones you click on buttonBuscar, the first button btnPago1 gets enabled. and when you click it, it gets disabled and the btnPago2 gets enabled. And that happens with all the buttons until the last button is clicked

Comment: Your code has too much redundancy, demasiada redundancia, making it difficult for us to understand and for you to debug. Consider using arrays or ArrayLists to shorten your code significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole actionPerfomed logic will be performed if eventSource is if `buttonBuscar`

```
if (evento.getSource() == buttonBuscar) {
```

Remove this line and your code should start working for all buttons. Also, please read this link for [SSCCE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Don't use one ActionListener for everything.
- Instead use one ActionListener, or AbstractAction for each sub-type of action.
- Your program has two main distinct actions:

  1. Pressing the Buscar button -- so give it its own ActionListener or AbstractAction
  2. And pressing the individual Pagos buttons -- so give them their own ActionListener or AbstractAction that is different from that of the Buscar button.
- Again, you can **greatly** simplify your code by using collections. This will reduce redundancy, and simplify coding, debugging, and enhancing.
- Avoid having your GUI's implement listener interfaces as this limits you to one listener method per type of listener used, and gives the GUI too much direct responsibility.
- Better to use either anonymous inner listeners, or private inner class listeners, or separate stand alone class listeners.
- Consider creating a class to hold a single JLabel and JButton, and creating a collection of these. This would make it easier for you to enable or disable both the button and the label together.
- Consider using a JCombBox or a JSpinner instead of your JTextField. This will limit the user's selection to only those allowed and thus reduce possible errors.

---

For instance, you could create a class, here I've called ButtonLabel, that would allow you to combine a JLabel and a JButton, something as simple as,

```
/**
 * class ButtonLabel </p>
 * Description: 
 * Putting a JButton and JLabel together will
 * make it easier to enable and disable both at the same time
 */
class ButtonLabel {
   private int index;
   private JLabel label;
   private JButton button;

   public ButtonLabel(int index, JLabel label, JButton button, boolean enabled) {
      this.index = index;
      this.label = label;
      this.button = button;
      label.setEnabled(enabled);
      button.setEnabled(enabled);
   }

   public int getIndex() {
      return index;
   }

   public JLabel getLabel() {
      return label;
   }

   public JButton getButton() {
      return button;
   }

   public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
      label.setEnabled(enabled);
      button.setEnabled(enabled);
   }

   public boolean isEnabled() {
      return button.isEnabled();
   }
}
```

Then the main GUI could hold a collection of these, perhaps an array or an ArrayList or a HashMap, all depending on how you'd want to access your buttons.

---

Your Pagar buttons could have their own Action/ActionListener, something like:

```
private class ButtonLabelAction extends AbstractAction {
  private int index;

  public ButtonLabelAction(String name, int index) {
     super(name);
     this.index = index;
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // TODO: code for each pagar button's action
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PanelPagos2.this,
           "You've pressed Pagos button #" + index);
  }
}
```

and this could have code specific to the Pagar button's need.

---

The Buscar button could have its own Action/ActionListener, for example,

```
private class BuscarAction extends AbstractAction {

  public BuscarAction(String name) {
     super(name);
     int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
     putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // assuming use of a JComboBox called pagoCombo
     String selection = (String) pagoCombo.getSelectedItem();

     // assuming use of a HashMap called btnLabelMap that
     // holds ButtonLabel values matched to a String key.
     for (ButtonLabel btnLabel : btnLabelMap.values()) {
        btnLabel.setEnabled(false);
     }
     if (selection != null && !selection.trim().isEmpty()) {
        btnLabelMap.get(selection).setEnabled(true);
     }
  }
}
```

---

For example,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PanelPagos2 extends JPanel {
   public static final int PAGO_CUENTA = 12;
   private Map<String, ButtonLabel> btnLabelMap = new HashMap<String, ButtonLabel>();
   private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> pagoComboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
   private JComboBox<String> pagoCombo = new JComboBox<String>(pagoComboModel);

   public PanelPagos2() {
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
      JPanel scrolledPanel = new JPanel();
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(scrolledPanel);
      scrollPane
            .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
      scrolledPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      pagoComboModel.addElement("");
      for (int i = 0; i < PAGO_CUENTA; i++) {
         int index = i + 1;
         String indexText = String.valueOf(index);
         pagoComboModel.addElement(indexText);
         String labelText = String.format("Pago #%02d:", index);
         JLabel label = new JLabel(labelText);
         ButtonLabelAction buttonLabelAction = new ButtonLabelAction("Pagar", index);
         JButton button = new JButton(buttonLabelAction);
         ButtonLabel btnLabel = new ButtonLabel(index, label, button, false);
         btnLabelMap.put(indexText, btnLabel);
         scrolledPanel.add(label, createGbc(0, i));
         scrolledPanel.add(button, createGbc(1, i));
      }

      JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
      int psWidth = viewport.getPreferredSize().width;
      int psHeight = viewport.getPreferredSize().height / 2;
      Dimension prefSize = new Dimension(psWidth, psHeight);
      viewport.setPreferredSize(prefSize);

      mainPanel.add(new JLabel("ID:"));
      mainPanel.add(pagoCombo);
      mainPanel.add(new JButton(new BuscarAction("Buscar")));

      add(mainPanel);
      add(scrollPane);
   }

   private static GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      gbc.anchor = x == 0 ? GridBagConstraints.WEST : GridBagConstraints.EAST;
      gbc.fill = x == 0 ? GridBagConstraints.BOTH
            : GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      int right = x == 0 ? 3 : 0;
      int left = right;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(0, left, 0, right);
      return gbc;
   }

   private class BuscarAction extends AbstractAction {

      public BuscarAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String selection = (String) pagoCombo.getSelectedItem();
         for (ButtonLabel btnLabel : btnLabelMap.values()) {
            btnLabel.setEnabled(false);
         }
         if (selection != null && !selection.trim().isEmpty()) {
            btnLabelMap.get(selection).setEnabled(true);
         }
      }
   }

   private class ButtonLabelAction extends AbstractAction {
      private int index;

      public ButtonLabelAction(String name, int index) {
         super(name);
         this.index = index;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // TODO: code for each pagar button's action
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PanelPagos2.this,
               "You've pressed Pagos button #" + index);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      PanelPagos2 mainPanel = new PanelPagos2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("PanelPagos2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

/**
 * class ButtonLabel </p>
 * Description: 
 * Putting a JButton and JLabel together will
 * make it easier to enable and disable both at the same time
 */
class ButtonLabel {
   private int index;
   private JLabel label;
   private JButton button;

   public ButtonLabel(int index, JLabel label, JButton button, boolean enabled) {
      this.index = index;
      this.label = label;
      this.button = button;
      label.setEnabled(enabled);
      button.setEnabled(enabled);
   }

   public int getIndex() {
      return index;
   }

   public JLabel getLabel() {
      return label;
   }

   public JButton getButton() {
      return button;
   }

   public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
      label.setEnabled(enabled);
      button.setEnabled(enabled);
   }

   public boolean isEnabled() {
      return button.isEnabled();
   }
}
```

Comment: @mprabhat: thanks. It's funny that the only people voting on this question are the two of us, you up-voted me, and I up-voted you (yesterday).

Comment: Haha, I actually came back to this question to see if someone has provided a better way of handling such huge block of actionPerformed. Glad I came back, your suggestion list is really nice